# Error in X %*% diag(diagU[indi]) : non-conformable arguments with GAMM4

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv, gamm4

I've started working with gams recently and I am having a bit of trouble with gamm.
I built my model with the gam function and everything runs smoothly with the following code.

gamtot <- gam(activity_b~
s(Temp_cal,bs="tp",k=10)+s(wind,bs="tp",k=10)+s(precipitation, bs="tp",k=10)
+s(ntime,k=7, bs="cc")+s(Jday,bs="tp")+ s(Age,bs="tp",k=10)+ Sex + Site +
s(Temp_cal,by=Sex,k=10, bs="tp") + ti(Temp_cal,Age,bs=c("tp","tp")) +
s(Temp_cal, by=Site ,k=10, bs="tp") +
ti(Temp_cal,ntime, by=Site, bs=c("tp","cc")) + ti(Temp_cal,wind,bs=c("tp","tp")) +
ti(Temp_cal,precipitation,bs=c("tp","tp")),
family = binomial,data = dfc
)

But once I use gamm4 i get the following error message

gammtot <- gamm4(activity_b~

```
            s(Temp_cal,bs="tp",k=10)+s(wind,bs="tp",k=10)+s(precipitation, bs="tp",k=10)

           +s(ntime,k=7, bs="cc")+s(Jday,bs="tp")+ s(Age,bs="tp",k=10)+ Sex + Site +
             s(Temp_cal,by=Sex,k=10, bs="tp") + t2(Temp_cal,Age,bs=c("tp","tp")) +
             s(Temp_cal, by=Site ,k=10, bs="tp") +
             t2(Temp_cal,ntime, by=Site, bs=c("tp","cc")) + t2(Temp_cal,wind,bs=c("tp","tp")) +
             t2(Temp_cal,precipitation,bs=c("tp","tp")),
           family = binomial, data = dfc)
```

Error in X %*% diag(diagU[indi]) : non-conformable arguments

I haven't even added the random effects just using gamm4 with the same code doesn't work. I can't seem to understand why.

Any help would be very much appreciated